# Execute ssh on windows via python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, subprocess

I am trying to excute an ssh commoand:
ssh -t user1@hostname "sudo su - user2 -s /bin/bash"

my code below does not work:

```
expectations = [('password', '******')]
cmd = ['ssh','-t','user1@hostname','"','sudo','su','-','user2','-s','/bin/bash', '"']
try:
    clean_non_empty_lines = []

    expectations = [(None, None)] + expectations

    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        bufsize=1)

    last_line = None

    for expectation, response in expectations:

        if expectation is not None:
            expectation = re.compile('$(.*)' + expectation + '(.*)')

        if expectation is not None and expectation.search(last_line):
            stdout, stderr = p.communicate(input=bytes(response, 'utf-8'))
        else:
            stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

        if stderr is not None:
            error = str(stderr.decode('ascii')).rstrip()
            print(error)

        if stdout is not None:
            last_line = stdout.decode('utf8')

            for line in iter(re.split('\r\n|\n', last_line)):
                line = str(line.rstrip())

                if line != '':
                    print(line)

                    line = line.strip()

                    if line:
                        clean_non_empty_lines += [line]

    p.stdout.close()
    p.wait()
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
> ```

Is there a way to get this to work? So that after executing sudo su - user2.... the program responds to the password prompt with the password specified in the variable 'expectations'?

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://pypi.org/project/pysftp/ i have used this prior to make my own termius like app but ended up using electron with node child processes and mongo.

p.s i scraped the while project later cause i couldn't figure out how to get a terminal window in electron.

Comment: This is for doing sftp, not what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be relevant to you because of the `su` command but i might get you one step closer:

My desktop is Windows and I have to frequently login to my ISP's shared Linux server. For this I use `putty` as my client. To avoid having to provide my password at login, I use [PuTTYgen](https://www.puttygen.com/) to generate a public/private key pair. The former I installed on my server through its cPanel facility and the later went into `C:\Users\my-windows-id\.ssh\id_rsa`. I an now able to execute via `SSH` Linux commands with:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

WINDOWS = False

private_key_file = r'C:\Users\my-windows-id\.ssh\id_rsa' if WINDOWS else '/c/Users/my-windows-id/.ssh/id_rsa'
p = Popen(f'ssh -i "{private_key_file}" my-domain.com', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate(b'cat malware.txt\nlogout\n')
print('stdout:\n')
print(stdout.decode())
print('stderr:\n')
print(stderr.decode())
p.wait()
```

There was a problem, however, when I tried to run this from a Windows command prompt (with the `WINDOWS` variable above set to TRUE). The following message popped up:

```
The authenticity of host 'my-domain.com (xx.xx.xx.xx)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 0b:a6:08:39:d9:a1:90:2f:bd:a2:ff:2e:67:2d:1a:1f.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

I specified `yes` to see what would happen even though I should have never gotten that message to begin with. The program did run, but among the output in the `stderr` output was:

```
Could not create directory '/home/my-windows-id/.ssh'.
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/my-windows-id/.ssh/known_hosts).
```

Now I am not sure why exactly I got this error. I happened to have a `C:\home` directory that is a junction directory and perhaps that is the cause of the problem. But this is the wrong directory to be looking for the `known_hosts` file, which should already have the necessary entry. I happened to have `Git` installed under Windows and thus a `Git Bash` shell under which I can run the program:

```
$ python test.py
stdout:


----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 2086420
Engine version: devel-clamav-0.99-beta1-632-g8a582c7
Scanned directories: 9499
Scanned files: 91169
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 2075.55 MB
Data read: 11297.00 MB (ratio 0.18:1)
Time: 772.194 sec (12 m 52 s)


----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 2086420
Engine version: devel-clamav-0.99-beta1-632-g8a582c7
Scanned directories: 0
Scanned files: 0
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 0.00 MB
Data read: 0.00 MB (ratio 0.00:1)
Time: 4.328 sec (0 m 4 s)


----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 2086420
Engine version: devel-clamav-0.99-beta1-632-g8a582c7
Scanned directories: 0
Scanned files: 20
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 0.94 MB
Data read: 0.56 MB (ratio 1.67:1)
Time: 4.587 sec (0 m 4 s)


stderr:

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
TERM environment variable not set.
```

The `stderr` output has a couple of messages including one pertaining to `stdin`, but the `cat` command does work.

**This will get you pass the initial login if that is causing an issue. Perhaps you can then install a second public/private key pair for the second login. I am just not sure that once the SSH connection has been made whether that would have an effect for the `su` command.**